# Checkbox and RadioButon in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, expandablelistview

Can anyone help me, please. How to make in ChildView some childs with checkbox and some with Radio Button?
Now i have childs with only checkbox, but i need to replace some of them with radio. Thanks.

Comment: not clears question explain more

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar i have an expandable list view. Child items have checkboxes. However, i need in some child items make not a checkbox but a radio button.

Comment: have u adapter of list view

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar yes, of course. And i have getChildView method.

Comment: please pass some true or false value in Adapter and set something like checkbox.setVisibility(true);
rediobutton.setvisibility(false);

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have both the checkbox and radio button in your xml. And when you need checkbox to be displayed:

```
checkbox.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
rediobutton.setvisibility(INVISIBLE);
```

when you need radiobutton to be displayed:

```
rediobutton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
checkbox.setvisibility(INVISIBLE);
```

simple.

Comment: it helped me to see Radio Button! And now, i suppose, i should make RadioGroup to be able to choose only one button from, for example, 3.